# How can i remove the even number indexes in a list of tuples?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I have a tuple list like this:

```
   lis__ = [('string', 'id1',...,'string', 'idn')]
```

With different `ids` and `strings`. How can I remove the `ids` from this tuple list?, the ids look like this `DSDF2342` and they are different. For example:

```
   lis__ = [('string', '234SDFSD',...,'string', 'DFSFSD234')]
```

The desired output would be something like this:

```
[(string string .... string)]
```

Thanks in advance guys. This is what I tried:

```
my_list = [tuple([j.split()[0] for j in i]) for i in lis__]

print my_list
```

Comment: Thanks for the feed @AvinashRaj I updated

Comment: your problem would be solved on very first if you write "How can i remove the even number indexes in a list of tuples" instead of `How can I remove the ids from this tuple list?,`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A good solution:

```
my_list = [t[::2] for t in lis__]
```

The **slice** `t[::2]` takes only items with an even index (0, 2, 4, &c).

Comment: This works, in fact I tried to use the slice but I didnt know how to use it. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Just curious, does this work because the data is in a tuple which is immutable instead of a list? I'm thinking that for a list after the first selected element is removed the rest of the list is sort of shifted toward the front like a linked list would be.

Comment: @Marichyasana, no, it would work just as well if `t` was a list -- the slicing would then make another list (while slicing a tuple makes a tuple).  All Python sequences work this way (strings too, which I personally keep finding weird after over a decade of Python guru-hood:-).

Comment: @Marichyasana, the slice returns a new list

Answer (score 2):

This will give you a list of items that do *not* contain items that startwith "id":

```
t = ('string', 'id1',...,'string', 'idn')
no_ids = [ item for item in t if not item.startswith("id")]
```

If you want to remove the *odd* indexed items you can also use `range()`, to provide the desired indexes. (*Where the positional arguments are `range(start, stop, step)`*):

```
t = ('string', 'id1',...,'string', 'idn')
no_ids = [ t[idx] for idx in range(0, len(t), 2)]
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but the ids doesnt start with id, they are long strings with different characters. I updated the question.

Comment: then how we differentiate between id's and strings?

Comment: very different... there is no way of using a regex or something like that.. thanks!

Comment: we differentiate based on location in the list, which must be guaranteed (and it is in python)